# How to convert the existing ASP.NET server control into MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET custom server control that inherits from the Panel control. It adds its own JavaScript and styles to the page using ScriptManager. Now some users ask me if I can update it so they can use it in MVC. What can be done here? Any references, links, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can be done here?

Sorry to disappoint you but a total rewrite and re-engineering is required. ASP.NET MVC is an entire different pattern than classic WebForms which relied on server side controls and (may God forbid) ScriptManagers. Depending on what this control is doing and the functionality it exposes there might be different ways to *migrate it* to MVC. One way would be to use custom Html helpers along with custom jQuery plugins.